# I am getting some error during latex compilation, but i have no idea about this

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, pdftex

I encountered a Latex error message that says：

`Can be used only in preamble.`
`Command \citename already defined.`
`Command \bibhang already defined.`

`Package biblatex: Incompatible package 'natbib'.`
`Command \Citeauthor already defined.`

`Command \bibfont already defined.`

I realize that this issue might originate from invalid hyperlinks in my references, figures, and tables.

I have already defined the Latex file before the body：

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter
\let\c@author\relax
\makeatother

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\expandafter\let\csname equation*\endcsname\relax
\expandafter\let\csname endequation*\endcsname\relax
\usepackage{amsmath}
% \usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}   

\journal{}

\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
.
.
.
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num} 
\bibliography{re-ref.bib}
\end{document}
```

but I am still struggling to solve this problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX, please provide a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)

Comment: Also: You are using two packages for the bibliography (`biblatex` and `bibtex`). Remove either `\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric]{biblatex}` and `\addbibresource{references.bib}` or  `\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}` and `\bibliography{re-ref.bib}`. If you decide to go with biblatex, you need to add `\printbibliography` at the end of your document

Answer (score 2):

By default, the `elsarticle` class loads `natbib`, but this is incompatible with `biblatex`.

You *can* use `biblatex` with `elsarticle`, but then `\bibliographystyle` and `\bibliography` shouldn't be used.

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,nonatbib]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\makeatletter\let\c@author\relax\makeatother

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}% <-- replace with your bib file
\AddToHook{env/frontmatter/after}{\setcounter{author}{0}}

\journal{}

\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
.
.
.
\end{frontmatter}

\cite{doody}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to use `natbib`

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,nonatbib]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\journal{}

\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
.
.
.
\end{frontmatter}

\cite{doody}

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}% <-- replace with your bib file

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Appreciate your informative answer.